# Python AddIn button init not working as expected

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, python-addin

I have a toolbar with two buttons. It's a crude toggle that looks
at a text file containing a single character whose values are either 0 or 1.  When the file contents are 0, then button1 `ResumeExports()` should show up as depressed and disabled while button2 `PauseExports()` is enabled and normal.  When the contents of the file are 1, then the button2 should be active and button1 inactive--it is used as a switch to allow or disallow other processing to occur.  The toggle works, and the file gets updated.  How can I get the button status (checked/unchecked, enabled/disabled) on the interface to reflect that?  Both buttons always show enabled and unchecked.  I'm at 10.2.1.

```
import arcpy
import pythonaddins

class ResumeExports(object):
    """Implementation for PythonAddIns_addin.res_btn (Button)"""
    ctl_file = r"C:\Users\myusername\Documents\ArcGIS\switch.txt"
    def __init__(self):
        with open(ctl_file, 'r') as i:
            content = i.read(1)
        if content == '1':          # exports are allowed 
            self.enabled = False    # button should be inactive
            self.checked = True     # button should be depressed
        if content == '0': # exports are disallowed, resume button is active
            self.enabled = True
            self.checked = False
    def onClick(self):
        with open(ctl_file, "r+") as f:
            data = f.read()
            f.seek(0)
            f.write("1")
            f.truncate()       

class PauseExports(object):
    """Implementation for PythonAddIns_addin.stop_btn (Button)"""
    ctl_file = r"C:\Users\myusername\Documents\ArcGIS\switch.txt"
    def __init__(self):
        with open(ctl_file, 'r') as i:
            content = i.read(1)
        if content == '0':          # exports are paused
            self.enabled = False    # button should be inactive
            self.checked = True     # button should be depressed
        if content == '1': # exports are allowed, pause button is active
            self.enabled = True
            self.checked = False
    def onClick(self):
        ctl_file = r"C:\Users\myusername\Documents\ArcGIS\switch.txt"
        with open(ctl_file, "r+") as f:
            data = f.read()
            f.seek(0)
            f.write("0")
            f.truncate()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I re-wrote it to use a single button that appears depressed when external processing is turned off.

```
import arcpy
import pythonaddins

class PauseResumeExports(object):
    """Implementation for ExportControl_addin.button (Button)"""
    def __init__(self):
        ctl_file = r"C:\Users\myusername\Documents\ArcGIS\switch.txt"
        with open(ctl_file, 'r') as i:
            content = i.read(1)
        if content == '1':          # processing allowed, pause tool appears functional
            self.enabled = True     
            self.checked = False    
        if content == '0':          # processing not allowed to run, pause tool is disabled
            self.enabled = True
            self.checked = True

    def onClick(self): # pause exports; change "1" to "0"
        ctl_file = r"C:\Users\myusername\Documents\ArcGIS\switch.txt"
        # get current value of ctl_file... from _init_ button should already be set
        with open(ctl_file, 'r') as i:
            content = i.read(1)
        if content == '1':
            # exports are allowed to run; button press disables
            # 1) disable it (set to "0")
            with open(ctl_file, "r+") as f:
                data = f.read()
                f.seek(0)
                f.write("0")
                f.truncate()
                # 2) update button (set to checked)
                self.enabled = True     
                self.checked = True    
        if content == '0':
            # exports are administratively disabled; button press will enable
            # 1) disable it (set to "0")
            with open(ctl_file, "r+") as f:
                data = f.read()
                f.seek(0)
                f.write("1")
                f.truncate()
                # 2) update button (set to unchecked)
                self.enabled = True     
                self.checked = False
```